# SQLite Query to get last record for each id before inputted datetime

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a `SQLite` table of security prices that have timestamps from when each price was recorded. I'm trying to write a query were I can pass an arbitrary `price_datetime` input, say `2022-08-10 19:000:00.000000`, and pull the latest `price` for each `security_id` that is `<=` the inputed `price_datetime`.

Below is a sample table:

```
┌─────────────┬───────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ security_id │ price │       price_datetime       │
├─────────────┼───────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ 4           │ 90.0  │ 2022-08-11 20:00:00.000000 │
│ 1           │ 100.0 │ 2022-08-10 20:00:00.000000 │
│ 1           │ 90.0  │ 2022-08-10 19:00:00.000000 │
│ 2           │ 95.0  │ 2022-08-10 18:00:00.000000 │
│ 2           │ 90.0  │ 2022-08-09 20:00:00.000000 │
│ 1           │ 90.0  │ 2022-08-09 20:00:00.000000 │
│ 3           │ 90.0  │ 2022-08-08 20:00:00.000000 │
└─────────────┴───────┴────────────────────────────┘
```

The input `2022-08-10 19:000:00.000000` would return below:

```
┌─────────────┬───────┬────────────────────────────┐
│ security_id │ price │       price_datetime       │
├─────────────┼───────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ 4           │ null  │ null                       │
│ 1           │ 90.0  │ 2022-08-10 19:00:00.000000 │
│ 2           │ 95.0  │ 2022-08-10 18:00:00.000000 │
│ 3           │ 90.0  │ 2022-08-08 20:00:00.000000 │
└─────────────┴───────┴────────────────────────────┘
```

`security_id` 4 returns `null` since there is no price record with a `price_datetime` <= `2022-08-10 19:000:00.000000`. The query should also have the flexibility to return the last 1, 2, etc. records `<=` the inputted `price_datetime` in addition to just the last.

Code to generate the sample table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE prices (
    security_id INTEGER,
    price FLOAT NOT NULL, 
    price_datetime DATETIME NOT NULL

);

CREATE INDEX ix_prices_price_datetime on "prices" (price_datetime);

INSERT INTO prices VALUES(1,100,'2022-08-10 20:00:00.000000'),(1,90,'2022-08-10 19:00:00.000000'),(1,90,'2022-08-09 20:00:00.000000'),(2,90,'2022-08-09 20:00:00.000000'),(2,95,'2022-08-10 18:00:00.000000'),(3,90,'2022-08-08 20:00:00.000000'),(4,90,'2022-08-11 20:00:00.000000');

SELECT * FROM prices ORDER BY price_datetime DESC;
```

Comment: What you're looking for are [window functions](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/). Rank them partitioned by security_id and order by price_datetime.

Comment: Would `SELECT security_id, MAX(price_datetime), price from prices where price_datetime <= '2022-08-10 19:000:00.000000' GROUP BY security_id;` work except for the `null` and returning more than last 1?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `LEFT` join of the distinct `security_id`s to the table.

For the last price of each `security_id` the simplest way to get it is with aggregation, using SQLite's feature of [bare columns](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query):

```
SELECT s.security_id, p.price, MAX(p.price_datetime) price_datetime
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT security_id FROM prices) s
LEFT JOIN prices p ON p.security_id = s.security_id AND p.price_datetime <= '2022-08-10 19:000:00.000000'
GROUP BY s.security_id;
```

For the last *n* rows use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT s.security_id, p.price, p.price_datetime,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.security_id ORDER BY p.price_datetime DESC) rn
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT security_id FROM prices) s
  LEFT JOIN prices p ON p.security_id = s.security_id AND p.price_datetime <= '2022-08-10 19:000:00.000000'
)  
SELECT security_id, price, price_datetime
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= n; -- replace n with the number that you want
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=916888a13e58140abe0d75f840807213).

Comment: For your last `n` rows, how would you edit so if there were fewer than `n` results for a security, you would get the missing number of nulls? So if `n`=2, you have have 2 nulls for `security_id` 4, 1 null for `security_id` 3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH
    query_input(price_datetime, row_count) AS (
        VALUES (
            '2022-08-10 19:000:00.000000', -- @price_datetime,
            2                              -- @row_count
        )
    ),
    -- Remove this CTE when running against your db containing the actual "prices" table.
    prices(security_id, price, price_datetime) AS (
        VALUES 
            (1,  99,  '2022-08-10 20:00:00.000000'),  
            (1,  90,  '2022-08-10 19:00:00.000000'),  
            (1,  90,  '2022-08-09 20:00:00.000000'),  
            (2,  90,  '2022-08-09 20:00:00.000000'),  
            (2,  95,  '2022-08-10 18:00:00.000000'),  
            (3,  90,  '2022-08-08 20:00:00.000000'),  
            (4,  90,  '2022-08-11 20:00:00.000000')
    ),
    -- As you requested to show every security, you need to collect all id's.
    -- I assume you define table "securities" containing column "id", so that
    -- prices.security_id => securities.id. Remove the following query when
    -- running against your db and adjust the "ids" CTE below if necessary.
    securities(id) AS (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)),
    ids(id) AS (
        -- Adjust "id" and "securities" to match your schema
        SELECT id FROM securities
    ),
    filtered_prices AS (
        SELECT prices.*
        FROM prices, query_input
        WHERE prices.price_datetime <= query_input.price_datetime
    ),
    label_prices AS (
        SELECT
            fp.*,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY fp.security_id ORDER BY fp.price_datetime DESC) AS group_id
        FROM filtered_prices AS fp
    ),
    last_n_existing_prices AS (
        SELECT lp.*
        FROM label_prices AS lp, query_input AS qi
        WHERE lp.group_id <= qi.row_count
    ),
    last_n_prices AS (
        SELECT ids.id AS security_id, lp.price, lp.price_datetime
        FROM ids
        LEFT JOIN last_n_existing_prices AS lp
        ON ids.id = lp.security_id
        ORDER BY ids.id, lp.price_datetime DESC
    )
SELECT * FROM last_n_prices;
```